# r sparklyr spark_apply Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'id' is ambiguous

Tags: r, apache-spark, hive, sparklyr

I am trying to use spark_apply on a spark cluster to calculate kmeans on data grouped by two columns. The data is queried from Hive and looks like this

```
> samplog1
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 6]
# Database: spark_connection
                                     id        time1 latitude longitude           timestamp    hr
                                  <chr>        <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>               <chr> <int>
 1 fffc68e3-866e-4be5-b1bc-5d21b89622ae 1.509338e+12 1.373545  104.1265 2017-10-30 04:29:59     4
 2 fffc7412-deb1-4587-9c22-29ca833865ed 1.509332e+12 5.701320  117.4892 2017-10-30 02:49:47     2
 3 fffd16d5-83f1-4ea1-95de-34b1fcad392b 1.509338e+12 5.334012  100.2172 2017-10-30 04:25:44     4
 4 fffc68e3-866e-4be5-b1bc-5d21b89622ae 1.509338e+12 1.373545  104.1265 2017-10-30 04:29:44     4
 5 fffd16d5-83f1-4ea1-95de-34b1fcad392b 1.509332e+12 5.334061  100.2173 2017-10-30 02:58:30     2
 6 fffd16d5-83f1-4ea1-95de-34b1fcad392b 1.509339e+12 5.334012  100.2172 2017-10-30 04:55:41     4
 7 fffc7412-deb1-4587-9c22-29ca833865ed 1.509339e+12 5.729879  117.5787 2017-10-30 04:49:07     4
 8 fffc68e3-866e-4be5-b1bc-5d21b89622ae 1.509340e+12 1.373545  104.1265 2017-10-30 05:02:08     5
 9 fffc7412-deb1-4587-9c22-29ca833865ed 1.509325e+12 5.701320  117.4892 2017-10-30 00:53:12     0
10 fffc7412-deb1-4587-9c22-29ca833865ed 1.509336e+12 5.670300  117.4990 2017-10-30 04:08:12     4
```

The function I am passing to spark_apply is below. It is supposed to take the data group it by id and hr, calculate kmeans on each group, calculate what fraction of rows each group represents (confidence) and return the center with the highest number of members and the confidence:

```
kms <- function(idLogs){
  tryCatch({
  km <- sparklyr::ml_kmeans(idLogs, centers = 3, features = c("latitude","longitude"))

  km1 <- copy_to(sc, km$centers, overwrite = T)

  cluster <-  sdf_predict(km)

  clustCounts <- cluster %>% group_by(prediction) %>% 
    tally  %>%
    mutate(conf=n/sum(n),
           prediction=prediction+1)

  clustCounts1 <- merge(clustCounts, km1, by.x=3, by.y=0)

  clustCounts1 <- copy_to(sc, clustCounts1, overwrite = T)

  clustCounts2 <- clustCounts1 %>% filter(., conf==max(conf)) %>% select(latitude, longitude, conf)

  return(data.frame(clustCounts2))
  }, error = function(e) {
    return(
      data.frame(string_id = c(0), string_categories = c("error"))
    )
  })
}
```

and I am invoking it as

```
spark_apply(x = samplog1, f = kms, group_by = c("id","hr"))
```

However, I am receiving an error about ambiguous 'id' column.

```
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'id' is ambiguous, could be: id#1569, id#1571.;
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolve(LogicalPlan.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveChildren(LogicalPlan.scala:171)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4$$anonfun$26.apply(Analyzer.scala:470)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4$$anonfun$26.apply(Analyzer.scala:470)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$.withPosition(package.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:470)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:466)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:335)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:335)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:334)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:332)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:332)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:281)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:321)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:332)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionUp$1(QueryPlan.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$2(QueryPlan.scala:118)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$2$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:122)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$2(QueryPlan.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlan.scala:127)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsUp(QueryPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:466)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:346)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.apply(Analyzer.scala:346)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.apply(Analyzer.scala:327)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:83)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:80)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:111)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:72)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:72)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:37)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:37)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:133)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$withPlan(DataFrame.scala:2141)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.select(DataFrame.scala:721)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.selectExpr(DataFrame.scala:754)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sparklyr.Invoke$.invoke(invoke.scala:102)
at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:97)
at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.read(stream.scala:62)
at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:52)
at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:14)
at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToM
```

From the explanations I have seen this could happen when joining dataframes where an id is shared. In this case I am not joining any dataframes. The only possible culprit would be the merge function but the constituent dataframes do not have any id column. I am new to sparklyr and spark_apply so appreciate that I could have written my function totally wrong. I am posting the whole script below in case it may reveal other issues. I hope this does not clutter things up:

```
Sys.setenv(HIVE_HOME="/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hive/")

kms <- function(idLogs){
  tryCatch({
  km <- sparklyr::ml_kmeans(idLogs, centers = 3, features = c("latitude","longitude"))

  km1 <- copy_to(sc, km$centers, overwrite = T)

  cluster <-  sdf_predict(km)

  clustCounts <- cluster %>% group_by(prediction) %>% 
    tally  %>%
    mutate(conf=n/sum(n),
           prediction=prediction+1)

  clustCounts1 <- merge(clustCounts, km1, by.x=3, by.y=0)

  clustCounts1 <- copy_to(sc, clustCounts1, overwrite = T)

  clustCounts2 <- clustCounts1 %>% filter(., conf==max(conf)) %>% select(latitude, longitude, conf)

  return(data.frame(clustCounts2))
  }, error = function(e) {
    return(
      data.frame(string_id = c(0), string_categories = c("error"))
    )
  })
}

sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", 
                    version="1.6.0", 
                    spark_home = '/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/')

tbl_change_db(sc, "clustergps")

samplog <- tbl(sc, "part6")

samplog <- mutate(samplog, timestamp = from_unixtime(time1/1000))

samplog <- mutate(samplog, hr = hour(timestamp))

samplog1 <- samplog %>% filter(id == 'fffd16d5-83f1-4ea1-95de-34b1fcad392b' |
                   id == 'fffc7412-deb1-4587-9c22-29ca833865ed' |
                   id == 'fffc68e3-866e-4be5-b1bc-5d21b89622ae')


likelyLocs <- spark_apply(samplog1, kms, group_by = list("id","hr"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just to give some feedback on this. I was able to resolve the issue by setting the "columns" parameter of spark_apply that defines the names of the output columns. I found setting it to any string/vector of strings value worked.

Comment: Where's the code you used to achieve what you claim?